# Is the binary Time series form an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, time-series

Let A be the set of all binary time series. (for example, all spike trains between time t_1 and t_2)  I am looking for an operation *, such that (A,*) form a group.

Is the set of all spike trains  form an abelian group?

Comment: This may be more of a math question, not a data science question.

Comment: @SeanOwen: I agree - this question should be migrated to _Math.SE_.